# Distinct values from array field in Java+MongoDB

Tags: java, regex, mongodb, mongodb-java, morphia

I have two documents in a products collection:

```
{ _id: '123', name:'tv abc', categories:['electronics','promo','cellbattery'] },
{ _id: '124', name:'phone xyz', categories:['electronics','sim','cellphones','promo'] }
```

I want my users to type in a search input text field 'el' and get this list:

```
['electronics','cellbattery','cellphones']
```

I wrote this query:

```
DBCollection collection = getDatastore().getCollection(Products.class);
        DBObject query = new BasicDBObject( "categories", Pattern.compile(queryTerm) );
        return collection.distinct( "categories", query );
```

where queryTerm is 'el' and the first line is from Morphia and simply gets the collection.

Unfortunately it is returning the whole list of categories, distinct values, instead of just the ones matching the regex.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this will be really slow. have you looked at MongoDB's fulltext-search capabilities?

Comment: sure. how  that would apply to my case? I mean, I need to "distinct" my array values

Comment: I think you could replace the regex in the aggregation pipeline with fulltext search: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/text-search-in-aggregation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an array element satisfies the query criteria specified in find/distinct, the entire document is returned and **NOT** just the matching array elements. To achieve what you want, you'll need to use the [`aggregation framework`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/).  I have provided the Mongo query below which can be executed in shell.  This should help you rewrite it in Java.

```js
db.Products.aggregate([
    // Match only those documents that have atleast one category satisfying regex `/el/`
    {$match: {categories: /el/}}, 
    // De-normalize the 'categories' array
    {$unwind: "$categories"}, 
    // Get only those array elements matching regex '/el/'
    {$match: {categories: /el/}}, 
    // Group by the array elements to get distinct value
    {$group: {_id: "$categories"}}
])
```